# Nested template specialization results in "Illegal use of explicit template arguments"?

Tags: c++, templates

How do I specialize a nested template? (See error below.)

```
using std::reverse_iterator;

template<typename It>
reverse_iterator<It> make_reverse_iterator(const It &it)
{
    return reverse_iterator<It>(it);
}

template<typename It>
It make_reverse_iterator<reverse_iterator<It> >(const reverse_iterator<It> &it)
{
    // Above                     ^
    // error C2768:
    //   'make_reverse_iterator': illegal use of explicit template arguments
    return it.base();
}
```

Comment: Where is the nested template in the example? All I see is a partial function specialization, which is not allowed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Maybe I used the wrong term... I meant specializing for the templated `reverse_iterator<It>`, based on the (nested) type `It`.

Comment: Partial specialization of function templates is not allowed -- isn't this what's going on here?

Comment: @Jon: Perhaps..? I don't know, what's "partial" about it? It looks fully specialized to me (unless I'm misunderstanding the term).

Comment: You are trying to specialize `make_reverse_iterator` for any type parameter which is a `reverse_iterator<It>` -- thus constraining the set of type parameters to which the specialization will apply only partially (the `It` is still open, but it does have to be a `reverse_iterator<It>`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a partial specialization of a function template. This is not allowed.

You can solve the problem in this example with an overload instead:

```
template<typename It>
It make_reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<It> &it)
{
    return it.base();
}
```

In cases where overloads don't work you can resort to partial specialization of class templates.

Comment: I was under the impression that the usual workaround is overloading the function...?

Comment: @Jon: Oh, I didn't notice that overloading actually worked in this case (it's not always possible to do it with overloads) Thanks, will edit.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [partial function template specialization](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm), which is not allowed. You can however achieve the same effect by overloading the function:

```
template<typename It>
It make_reverse_iterator(const reverse_iterator<It> &it)
{
    return it.base();
}
```

The above is not a template specialization, but a template overload of `make_reverse_iterator` where the parameter is a `const_reverse_iterator<It>`.

Comment: Something tells me [Dimov/Abrahams](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) might apply here, and so only *one* of the solutions here is correct, but not both (overloading or specialization, I do not know which). Any idea?